# Send multiple tab key presses with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I send multiple tabs with Selenium?

When I run:

```
uname = browser.find_element_by_name("text")
uname.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

the next element is selected. When executing `uname.send_keys(Keys.TAB)` again nothing happens - actually the next element from `uname` is selected → so it is the same as when running it once.

How can I jump forward multiple times - basically as I would press <kbd>TAB</kbd> manually multiple times?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [Action Chains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

N = 5  # number of times you want to press TAB

actions = ActionChains(browser) 
for _ in range(N):
    actions = actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
actions.perform()
```

Or, since this is Python, you can even do:

```
actions = ActionChains(browser) 
actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * N)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: in my case I needed to import **Keys**:   `from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import Keys`

Comment: for me it's `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`

Comment: I can move the cursor with the `send_keys(Keys.TAB)` to the **OK** button, but the `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` doesn't do anything. The **focus** is not on the file download dialog.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can also write

```
uname.send_keys(Keys.TAB + Keys.TAB + Keys.TAB + ... )
```

It may be useful if you have only two or three commands to send.

Answer (score 1):

```
uname.send_keys(Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB, Keys.TAB..)
```

worked for me.

Comment: Literally "`Keys.TAB..`"?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP states: "actually the next element from `uname` is selected".

After the first `<TAB>` key you have moved off the element, so no further `<TAB>`s will be recognized *by that element*. You need to locate the *parent* element and send keys to *it*.

Comment: at least someone is aware...

Answer (score 0):

`sendkeys(Keys.Tab, Keys.Tab, Keys.Tab)` is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax saved me:

```
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.TAB * 2).perform()
```

---

I tried using this from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385221/send-multiple-tab-key-presses-with-selenium/35385258#35385258):

```
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 2)
actions.perform()
```

But since I wanted to later use three TABs in the same script, I ran into problems. The thing is that `actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 3)` simply *adds* to the previous lines in `actions` in the same script. So after the second time I use this line, instead of desired three TAB keys pressed I get five (i.e. 2 + 3). Furthermore, [`ActionChains.reset_actions()` does not seem to work](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6837).

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow each send_keys with switchto like this -

```
for i in range(10):
    elem.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    elem = driver.switchTo().activeElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

In truth, to understand why send_keys isn't working with your html, it would be useful to see the html that you've got rendered.
Go to the page with the element that you're trying to test, and right-click on the element, then select 'Inspect', and copy/paste that into your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31888899)