# WebElement has no Attribute w3c

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action

I am trying to tab through an Instagram page given a user input.  I am able to get to the page.  The page loads, then the class is found, then the code breaks. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import time

def get_posts(tag, user_count):

    '''Getting html of page to be scrape for
    hrefs that will get me the user names'''

    print("getting page")
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + tag + "/"
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        print("successfully requested site")
    except:
        print("Unable to reach site")
        quit()

    browser = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_si7dy')
    actions = ActionChains(browser)
    for i in range(user_count):
        actions = actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    actions.perform()



    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

    try:
        posts = soup.find_all("div", class_ = ["_mck9w","_gvoze","_f2mse"])
    except:
        print("No links found")
        quit()

    print("Length of posts: ",(len(posts)))

    print(len(posts))
    print(type(posts))
    print("All Done")
    driver.close()
    return posts
```

I keep getting this error:

```
packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 69, in __init__
        if self._driver.w3c:
    AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'w3c'
```

I have searched around but have not found any info on w3c.  I have never tabbed down a page before and so am using the answer found here: [Send multiple tab key presses with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385221/send-multiple-tab-key-presses-with-selenium).

ActionChains seems like the best way to tab multiple times down the page, but if anyone has a better method I am open to trying that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ActionChains` should receive `WebDriver`, but you are sending `WebElement` instead

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
```