# Python - Selenium, How to automate print in Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, printing, automation

Hello and happy Holidays!

I wrote a script where I open a webpage in chrome, login, go to a certain page and then trying to print that page.
When the Chrome print preview comes up, I can not target the print button neither try to just hit enter via automation. Nothing works.

Any ideas please?

Ps: This is a the code I wrote but the login information will be incorrect

Thank you in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from shutil import which
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()


chrome_path = which("chromedriver")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver")

name = '****'
password = '****'

driver.get(
    "https://www.winbank.gr/sites/corporate/el/Pages/default.aspx")

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))


username = driver.find_element_by_name('Username')
username.send_keys(name)

passwords = driver.find_element_by_name('Password')
passwords.send_keys(password)

passwords.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="ng-app"]/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[6]').click()

window_before = driver.window_handles[0]

time.sleep(6)


driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="ng-app"]/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/wb-pfm-transactions/div/div[2]/div/div[22]/div[2]').click()

time.sleep(3)


driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

driver.find_element_by_id('print').click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])


print('-------------test----------')

# driver.print = "function(){};"


keyboard.press(Key.enter)


driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/print-preview-app//print-preview-sidebar//print-preview-button-strip//cr-button[2]').click()
```

Comment: Hi - is there an error description about that?

Comment: No error. It just stops at the chrome print preview window and does not do anything. Which is this line of code: driver.find_element_by_id('print').click(). If i then press cancel and the window closes then the other lines get executed

Answer (score 0):

Usually when dealing with untargetable objects I use the tab key to navigate and enter to "click" the element currently focused, what you should do is:
1. Try to print it manually, but with using tabs to navigate and Enter to click
2. Keep track of all key presses needed 
3. Write your code accordingly 
**Edit:** Also, if you need help with automatically pressing keys please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385221/send-multiple-tab-key-presses-with-selenium) link.

Comment: Once the script gets executed it stops at the last window which is the chrome print preview. There I can not target the print button although it is visible. In reality I just need to press enter once and it should print. (if I do this with my physical keyboard it works). The problem is my code gets not executed beyond the live that opens the chrome print preview window. (driver.find_element_by_id('print').click() ). If i then press cancel the rest of the code gets executed which is strange... Please help

Comment: @Biobrolly I don't understand, no code gets executed when the print window is up?

Comment: The code gets executed until the print window is up. Then the remaining code is not executed. It stops at this code line : driver.find_element_by_id('print').click() which is the line that brings the print window up. If press cancel (print) and the window closes then the remaining code of the script gets executed